# Excel sort data in newspaper style columns

Tags: excel, sorting, spreadsheet

I have an excel sheet that has names and extension numbers. The sheet is designed to be printed as a reference and so it has the data split into 3 columns like how a newspaper is laid out.

```
EXT Name EXT Name  EXT Name
1   bob  4   pete  8   sam
2   dave 5   sally 9   john
```

I need to have excel sort this data on name, A-Z. I can only work out how to make it sort one column at a time and so I end up having to manaually sort the data every time I add or remove information.

Can excel sort all 3 columns top to bottom and left to right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247311) artikel helps.

Or u can try using the small function like

Column A

```
=SMALL($A$1:$A$9;0+ROWS(A$1:A1))
```

Column C

```
=SMALL($A$1:$A$9;30+ROWS(A$1:A1))
```

In this case you clone the sorted dataset, which is in two columns
The value for the B colums can be found using a vlookup. the value 0 and zero are an offset, so the length of the page is fixed

Comment: Thanks for this, I ended up ditching Excel and creating a web app to do the work instead. I guess the lesson here is use the right tool for the job :)